# VBA For .. Next loop trying to go through Toolbars buttons

Tags: vba, for-loop, ms-office, ms-word

I just started to use VBA in a Word 2007 (Office XP) an I try to create loop to go through all toolbars and through all the buttons contained in every toolbar.

I made this code

```
Public Sub PasteFromClipboard()
  Dim i As Long
  Dim j As Long
  Dim sCmdBar As CommandBar

      Dim thisCommandBar As CommandBar
      Dim thisCommandButton As CommandBarButton

  Debug.Print "Number", "Name", "Visible", "Built-in"
  For i = 1 To Application.CommandBars.Count
    Set sCmdBar = Application.CommandBars(i)
    If sCmdBar.Visible = True Then
        j = j + 1
        Debug.Print j, sCmdBar.Name, sCmdBar.Visible, sCmdBar.BuiltIn

      Dim X As Long
      Set thisCommandBar = Application.CommandBars(sCmdBar.Name)
       For X = 1 To thisCommandBar.Controls.Count - 1
           Set thisCommandButton = thisCommandBar.Controls(X)
           If thisCommandButton.Caption = "Paste" Then
               Dim a As Long
               a = a + 1
               Exit For
           End If
       Next X

    End If
  Next i
```

But I got Run-time error 13: Type mismatch  on the following line:

`Set thisCommandButton = thisCommandBar.Controls(X).`

Why this happen and how to correct it?

One more question. Is it possible to change the condition in the way, to find caption of the button when it is written in local language? Not English. In the Word I am using, in Clipboard pane, there are buttons titled like "Vložit vše" (Insert all) and "Vymazat vše" (Delete all) and "Možnosti" (Options). And I want to find the toolbar which contains these three buttons (but of sure I don't know the real English captions).

Answer (score 0):

I have make it working using For Each

```
  Dim i As Long
  Dim j As Long
  Dim sCmdBar As CommandBar

      Dim thisCommandBar As CommandBar
      Dim thisCommandButton As CommandBarButton

  Debug.Print "Number", "Name", "Visible", "Built-in"
  For i = 1 To Application.CommandBars.Count
    Set sCmdBar = Application.CommandBars(i)
    If sCmdBar.Visible = True Then
        j = j + 1
        Debug.Print j, sCmdBar.Name, sCmdBar.Visible, sCmdBar.BuiltIn

      Set thisCommandBar = Application.CommandBars(sCmdBar.Name)
       For Each Ctl In thisCommandBar.Controls
           If Ctl.Caption = "Paste" Then
               Dim a As Long
               a = a + 1
               Exit For
           End If
       Next

    End If
  Next i
```

Comment: Performance tip: the outer loop should also be a `For Each` loop. You're iterating an object collection, use a `For Each` loop. Use `For...Next` loops when you're iterating arrays.

Comment: It was just a code to a test. I did not devoted attention to performance or nice style. I wanted just to make a simple code to search the toolbars...

Comment: When you start realizing that iterating an object collection by index with a `For` loop instead of a `For Each` loop runs up to 27 times slower, maybe it'll sink in.